# Sort doubly linked list by next id Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, doubly-linked-list, ramda.js

I want to sort doubly linked list by `next_id` value.

My DLL:

```
const dll = [
  {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'},
  {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null},
  {id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'},
  {id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'},
]
```

As a result:

```
const dll_result = [
  {id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'}, // next item - 41
  {id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'}, // next item - 22
  {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'}, // next item - 45
  {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null},
]
```

I understand that it may not make sense to sort the DLL, but in my case I need to sequentially visualize the data from the array using `next_id`.

**P.S.** It would be nice to know even a native solution, and then I could try to convert to Ramda.js myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index of items by `id`, find the 1st item (`prev_id` === null), and then iterate with a while loop, and push the current object into the result array:

```js
const findStart = R.find(R.propEq('prev_id', null))
const indexById = R.indexBy(R.prop('id'))

const sortByNextId = arr => {
  const index = indexById(arr)
  let current = findStart(arr)
  
  const sorted = []
  
  while(current) {
    sorted.push(current)
    current = index[current.next_id]
  }
  
  return sorted
}

const dll = [
  {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'},
  {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null},
  {id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'},
  {id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'},
]

const result = sortByNextId(dll)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Native approach*

You can sort by `id` and pick the lowest `id` as the first element of the desired output, then you can push the next elements by finding the next node using the attribute `next_id`.

```js
const dll = [{id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'},{id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null},{id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'},{id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'}],
      result = [[...dll].sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).shift()];

dll.forEach(() => result.push(dll.find(({id}) => id === result[result.length - 1].next_id)));
console.log(result);
```