# Move in doubly linked list Ramda.js

Tags: arrays, doubly-linked-list, ramda.js

When I started using a doubly linked list, it became more difficult to manage `prev_id` & `next_id`.

```
const dll = [
  {id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'}, // <- source
  {id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'}, 
  {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'},
  {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null}, // <- destination
]
```

For example, I want to move object `14` to the end, so the array should become:

```
const dll_result = [
  {id: '41', prev_id: null, next_id: '22'}, 
  {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'},
  {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: '14'},
  {id: '14', prev_id: '45', next_id: null},
]
```

The hardest thing what I need to do to change the `prev_id` & `next_id` of the objects?

My attempt:

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.27.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const {move} = R

  const dll = [
    {id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'}, //<- source
    {id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'}, //<- destination
    {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'}, 
    {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null}, 
  ]

  const fromId = '14'
  const toId = '41' 

  const fromItem = dll.find(item => item.id === fromId)
  const toItem = dll.find(item => item.id === toId)

  const updated = dll.map(item => {
    if (item.id === fromId) {
      return {...item, prev_id: toId, next_id: toItem.next_id}
    } else if (item.prev_id === fromId) {
      return {...item, prev_id: fromItem.prev_id}
    } else if (item.id === toItem.next_id) {
      return {...item, prev_id: fromId} 
    } else if (item.id === toId) {
      return {...item, next_id: fromId}    
    } else {
      return item
    }
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(move(0, 1, updated), null, 2))
</script>
```

Comment: Would you need the items to be immutable? IE clone an object when changing its next/prev?

Comment: @OriDrori, yes, I use this data structure in Redux, so this is the main reason why I use Ramda

Comment: Do you have control of the data structure being used and if so, which features of the double linked list do you specifically need? There may be other data structures that could be useful for you.

Comment: @ScottChristopher, I already have an insert and delete function. `Move` is the last of these functions

Comment: I would guess that the reason for Scott Chrisotpher's question is that this looks much more like a serialization format for a linked list than a real linked list.  (And it's not even the simplest serialization format; an array would do fine.)  Linked lists have certain advantages (including efficient inserts/deletes) and certain disadvantages (including slower direct access).  But this format seems only to have disadvantages.  A real doubly linked list usually has nodes with `next` and `prev` properties/methods pointing to other nodes.

Comment: What does your `toId` mean here.  Does it mean move *after* that id?  If so, can you never move an item to the head of the list?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I agree that this is not a good idea to work with this data format. One of my projects uses this structure on the backend, and I need to visualize this data, maybe I chose the wrong direction to solve this problem

Comment: @ScottSauyet, This is same as `move(fromId, toId)`. `fromId` get id at index 0, `toId` get id at index 1

Comment: @Arthur: I would suggest that it might be better to use the back end data to hydrate a real linked list and then serialize it when you have to supply it back.  Then you could have a more useful structure for your work.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I decided to do as you suggested to reduce the number of operations. Useless question, but interesting:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this, 
hope it helps...

Moving an item in a double-linked list is not ideal since then you need to shift all the links...

```js
const move = (id, toIndex, list) => {
  const fromIndex = R.findIndex(
    R.whereEq({ id }), 
    list,
  );
  
  return R.move(fromIndex, toIndex, list);
};

// R.nth would cause cyclic dbl-list
const pickId = (i, list) => R.propOr(null, 'id', list[i]);

const shiftLinks = (item, i, list) => R.mergeRight(item, {
  prev: pickId(R.dec(i), list),
  next: pickId(R.inc(i), list),
});

const moveById = R.pipe(
  move,
  R.addIndex(R.map)(shiftLinks),
);  


// ==
const data = [
  {id: 'first', prev: null, next: 'second'}, 
  {id: 'second', prev: 'first', next: 'third'},
  {id: 'third', prev: 'second', next: 'fourth'},
  {id: 'fourth', prev: 'third', next: null},
];
console.log(
  // id: 'second', toIndex: 3, data: data
  moveById('second', 3, data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-buL0byPvI/XRDFscnSc/e0q+sLA65O9y+rbF+0O/4FE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: looks like it only works for the first element in the array: /

Comment: Thank you for reporting it... It should now be fixed :)

Comment: This is a very powerful answer. Thank you very much

Comment: This makes an interesting assumption, one which contradicted my own.  It assumes that the data is kept in order in the list.  The answer has been accepted, so I guess it works for the OP, but it feels odd, especially in light of the related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297661/.  If it must be kept in order, then an array without the `prev`/`next` links seems much more logical.  It also switches from `toId` to `toIndex`, which seems odd.

Comment: You're right, 
dbl-linked lists should not require to be ordered...

I just addressed op's direct need, 
without really considering dbl-linked lists as a whole

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comments, I find that this is an unlikely data structure, gaining none of the benefits of a true doubly linked list.  Also in the comments I asked about *before* versus *after* when inserting or moving an item.  This version assumes that what was meant was to move *after* the given node, noting where we might also want *before* versions of the functions.

Fair warning, it is ugly imperative code, mutating data structures willy-nilly inside its functions.  (Although not, of course at the function boundaries; I'm not a barbarian!)

You said in a comment that you already had `insert` and `delete` functions.  If so, you might be able to write a simple version of `move` the way I do here, simply inserting an altered copy of the removed node after the target one.

I do not try to place the inserted node in any particular place in the array; I assume from the data structure that just placing it at the end is not an issue.  If it is, we'd have to start mucking about with indices too.  That's not hard, but it's ugly.

This code has no error checking, leaving that as an exercise for the reader.  If you use an id that's not in the list, we're not responsible for what happens.  It might divide by zero, launch the missiles, or steal your boyfriend.  You've been warned.

```js
// or Ramda's `clone`, or whatever
const clone = (o) => JSON .parse (JSON .stringify (o))

const removeNode = (dll, id) => {
  const list = clone (dll)
  const byId  = (i) => list .find (({id}) => id === i)
  const node = byId (id)
  const prevNode = node .prev_id ? byId (node .prev_id) : null
  const nextNode = node .next_id ? byId (node .next_id) : null
  if (prevNode) prevNode .next_id = node .next_id
  if (nextNode) nextNode .prev_id = node .prev_id
  return list.filter(node => node .id !== id)
}

const insertAfter = (dll, id, item) => {
  const list = clone (dll)
  const byId  = (i) => list .find (({id}) => id === i)
  const node = byId (id)
  const nextNode = node .next_id ? byId (node .next_id) : null
  node .next_id = item .id
  if (nextNode) nextNode .prev_id = item .id
  return [...list, {
    ...item, 
    prev_id: node .id,
    next_id: nextNode ? nextNode .id : null
  }]
}

const moveAfter = (dll, fromId, afterId) => {
  const node = dll .find (({id}) => id == fromId)
  return insertAfter (removeNode (dll, fromId), afterId, node)
}

// and insertBefore, moveBefore

const dll = [
  {id: '14', prev_id: null, next_id: '41'},
  {id: '41', prev_id: '14', next_id: '22'},
  {id: '22', prev_id: '41', next_id: '45'}, 
  {id: '45', prev_id: '22', next_id: null}, 
]

console.log (
  moveAfter (dll, '14', '41')
)
```